# How to keep equal row spacing in list SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have created list in SwiftUI. Rows are with text some text are long and multiline.
There is default spacing between rows but for multiline rows spacing is less.

I am trying for equal spacing between all rows.

```
 var names = ["text", "text", "text multitext text multitext text multitext text multitext text multitext text multitext text multitextv text multitextv", "text","text"]

 List(names, id:\.self) {
                        Text($0)
 }
```

Thank You for help.

[image]

Comment: Include your code

Comment: @jnpdx I have added code... question is very straight forward and not much to show in code thats why didn’t add before

Comment: Maybe cells in a list have a minimum height.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez might be but if add 10 line text row height increase but yes spacing is  not same as 1 line row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explicitly set the vertical padding:

```
List(names, id:\.self) {
    Text($0)
    .padding(.vertical, 10)
}
```